# Leer todas las tablas de un html con Beautiful Soup 4 en Python

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

estoy intentando extraer todas las tablas por separado de un archivo html, para meterlas en dataframes y luego transformar los datos.

El problema es que con find_all('table'), solo me da la primera tabla, he probado incluso a exportar directamente la salida del find_all a un txt. El código en cuestión:

```
node_count = 0
for path in node_paths:
    html_text = bs4(open(path), 'html5lib')
    tables = html_text.find_all("table")
    f = open("myfile.txt", "a")
    f.write(str(table))
    f.close()
    df = pd.read_html(str(tables))[0]
    df.to_csv(f"temp_data/node{node_count}.csv")
    node_count+=1
```

Los html que abre, tienen 3 tablas.
Los imports están correctos, y no me da ningún error.

Comment: Quizás las otras tablas estén en iframes. Quizás el markup sea incorrecto y estén unas anidadas en otras. De todas formas ¿sabes que pandas tiene [`read_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) que encuentra las tablasde un html y al que incluso puedes pasar directamente una url?

Comment: Sabía que me faltaba algo en la explicación, son htmls locales, con tablas peladas. Probaré el read_html a ver qué tal tira, gracias.

Comment: Vale, hay que iterar en las tables, que contiene las tablas. Ahora a pegarme con las tablas anidadas de un html hecho por kenders borrachos. Cuando tenga una solución específica la subo.